# PHP Output in module

Tags: theming

I am creating a module that is outputting a static php page into my Drupal install. Here is my module file:

```
<?php

function mymodule_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['live_amplified/hello_world'] = array(
'title' => 'Live Amplified',
// describe the page for the menu system.  site visitors will not see this
'description' => 'Simple custom hook_menu() implementation.',
// function that is called when visiting the new path
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('static_page_form'),
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 );

return $items;
}

/**
* Implements hook_form().
*/
function static_page_form($form, &$form_state) {
// Add CSS and JS
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/static_page.css');
// Import your static HTML page
$form['html'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
'#markup' => file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/static_page.php'),
);
return $form;
}
```

In my static_page.php I have written my HTML, but when I try to add any PHP the browser doesn't recognize it. It doesn't output anything. I have tried just echo test and still nothing.

Comment: You're misusing `file_get_contents()` which simply reads a file into a string (it won't evaluate any PHP contained within it). Look into Drupal's `hook_theme`. That will allow you to create a custom template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a form items markup attribute just to print some HTML.
Instead,  change your menu item to a simple page function, not a drupal_get_form eg

```
$items['live_amplified/hello_world'] = array(
  'title' => 'Live Amplified',
  'description' => 'Simple custom hook_menu() implementation.',
  'page callback' => 'hello_world_page',
  'page arguments' => array('static_page_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

and add a simple function to return some markup

```
function hello_world_page() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

But as @Adam Balsam described, if you have a lot of content and want to parse another PHP file, you would do it using `file_get_contents()` but Drupal already has a way of dealing with this that uses it (although it may be convoluted)

You would use hook_theme.

First you need to declare your implementation, this does two things: tells Drupal to look for a template file (the file you want to render) at some location, and it exposes your template to prerocessing for adding variables.

Declare your theme

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'helloworld' => array(
      'template'  => 'hello-world',
      'path'      => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Create a preprocess function to give it some variables

```
function mymodule_preprocess_helloworld(&$vars) {
  $vars['who'] = "World";
}
```

Create a template file hello-world.tpl.php in /mymodule/templates/ with the content

```
<h2>Hello <?php print $who; ?> </h2>
```

Call it from where ever you like, in this case a menu page.

```
function hello_world_page() {
  return theme('helloworld');
}
```

At first it may seem a bit convoluted but it allows you to create templates with variables and exposes theme to themeing so other modules and themes can change both the variables and the markup.

Comment: no problem, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slightly different way to do it than @user1081275's approach.

My situation was that I wanted to turn off the PHP Filter module for security reasons and I had several pages that had PHP in the body field.

I created a module that I put at sites/all/modules called "customphppages'. It had the basic .info and a directory inside called 'pages' where there would be one tpl.php file for every page on the web site that I wanted to create this way.

The tpl.php files are just for the content. You don't need to copy page.tpl.php (like I did the first time)... just your content goes in the tpl.php file.

The example shows the declaration of two pages for the site.

The following is from customphppages.module

```
<?php
/* 
 *Implementation of hook_menu().
 */

function customphppages_menu() {


  $items['movies/the-wizard-of-oz'] = array( //this is the URL, what comes after example.com/
    'title' => 'The Wizard of Oz', // this is the page title
    'page callback' => 'page_oz', // function name... can be anything
    'access callback' => TRUE, // this means no access control for page
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, // the same for every new page
  );
   $items['books/brave-new-world'] = array(
    'title' => 'Brave New World',
    'page callback' => 'page_brave',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/*
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function customphppages_theme(){
  return array(
    'woz_template' => array( //function name called below
      'template' => 'woz', // what comes before '-tpl.php' in the file name for the file with the content. So the file would be at sites/modules/customphppages/pages/woz.tpl.php
      'path' => 'sites/all/modules/customphppages/pages' //path to folder containing tpl.php.
    ),
    'brave_template' => array(
      'template' => 'brave',
      'path' => 'sites/all/modules/customphppages/pages'
    ),
  );
}
/* 
 * One function here for each page. Function names are 
 * derived from the 'page callback' value in the 
 * $items array. The quoted argument for theme()
 * is the key in in the custom array in customphppages_theme() function.
 */
function page_oz() {
  return theme('woz_template');
}

function page_brave() {
  return theme('brave_template');
}
```